# r.out.gdal exports raster with projection but without extents

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis, gdal-translate, pcraster

Exporting raster with `r.out.gdal` with PCRaster driver gives two files - .map itself and .xml with projection and colormap. But... I can't find the information about extent. Projection is EPSG:4623 (Geographic).
When I open the .map in QGIS it comes unprojected. We see `0.0000000000000000,-6879.0000000000000000 : 6248.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000` - unprojected extent, Projection information is 'EPSG:4326 - WGS 84'.

```
CRS 
Spatial Extent  CRS: - Projected
X Minimum: 0
Y Minimum: 0
X Maximum: 0
Y Maximum: 0
Temporal Extent Start: 
End:
```

What should I do to get correctly projected rasters from GRASS in PCRaster format.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test using the North Carolina sample dataset, available from https://grass.osgeo.org.

Test case:

```
GRASS nc_spm_08_grass7/user1:~ > r.out.gdal elevation out=ele.pcr format=PCRaster createopt="PCRASTER_VALUESCALE=VS_SCALAR"
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
 100%
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Exporting raster data to PCRaster format...
 100%
r.out.gdal complete. File <ele.pcr> created.
```

Note that I looked up `PCRASTER_VALUESCALE` at https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pcraster.html

The resulting files are:

```
ele.pcr
ele.pcr.aux.xml
```

Checking the output with GDAL

```
gdalinfo ele.pcr
Driver: PCRaster/PCRaster Raster File
Files: ele.pcr
       ele.pcr.aux.xml
Size is 1500, 1350
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["NAD83(HARN) / North Carolina",
BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(HARN)",
    DATUM["NAD83 (High Accuracy Reference Network)",
        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4152]],
CONVERSION["unnamed",
    METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
        ID["EPSG",9802]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",33.75,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8821]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-79,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8822]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",36.1666666666667,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8823]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",34.3333333333333,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8824]],
    PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",609601.22,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8826]],
    PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8827]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["easting",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["northing",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
ID["EPSG",3358]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (630000.000000000000000,228500.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  PCRASTER_VALUESCALE=VS_SCALAR
  SOFTWARE=GRASS GIS 8.4.0dev with GDAL 3.6.4
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  630000.000,  228500.000) ( 78d46'27.41"W, 35d48'34.59"N)
Lower Left  (  630000.000,  215000.000) ( 78d46'28.63"W, 35d41'16.54"N)
Upper Right (  645000.000,  228500.000) ( 78d36'29.89"W, 35d48'33.08"N)
Lower Right (  645000.000,  215000.000) ( 78d36'32.01"W, 35d41'15.03"N)
Center      (  637500.000,  221750.000) ( 78d41'29.49"W, 35d44'54.91"N)
Band 1 Block=1500x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Palette
  Description = elevation
  Min=55.582 Max=156.329 
  NoData Value=-3.4028235e+38
  Metadata:
    COLOR_TABLE_RULES_COUNT=255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_0=5.558216e+01 5.597709e+01 68 1 84 68 2 86
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_1=5.597709e+01 5.637201e+01 68 2 86 69 4 87
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_10=5.953346e+01 5.992839e+01 71 16 99 71 17 100
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_100=9.509116e+01 9.548609e+01 42 118 142 42 119 142
...
  155: 245,230,31,255
  156: 251,231,35,255
  157: 0,0,0,0
```

The projection information has been exported.

What do `g.proj -w` and `g.region -p` report? May it be that no projection information had been originally defined in your GRASS GIS location (and EPSG:4623 is missing from the metadata)?